In Wikidata, can X be a subclass of Y if Y is a subclass of X?
I wrote a program to recursively identify all the subclasses of human and noticed that it got stuck in an infinite loop: human fetus and unborn child are subclasses of each other.
When I hear "subclass," I think of class hierarchies in object-oriented programming, where it doesn't make sense for two classes to be subclasses of each other. A compiler would throw an error. Do subclasses in Wikidata work differently, or did I find an error?
This help page says that the subclass property is transitive and that it

Is used to state that all the instances of one class are instances of another.

Nothing about this definition precludes X from being a subclass of Y if Y is already a subclass of X. Thus, if every human fetus is an unborn child and every unborn child is a human fetus, then it follows that they are subclasses of each other.
Perhaps people will dispute this particular example. But speaking generally, can two items be subclasses of each other? And if they can, does it follow that they are identical? That is, if all Xs are Ys, and all Ys are Xs, then does X = Y? (I see the human fetus is said to be the same as unborn child. It seems like their subclass relation implicitly says "yes, they are the same").
Also note the closely related human embryo, which shares the same relation with unborn child.
EDIT: I have since found that this is called a subsumption cycle. This page says:

A cycle is created if class A has a subclass B and B is a superclass of A.

Nothing else is said. There is neither an example nor an indication of whether these cycles are permitted. But perhaps this suggests that they are allowed.


But speaking generally, can two items be subclasses of each other? And if they can, does it follow that they are identical? That is, if all Xs are Ys, and all Ys are Xs, then does X = Y?

Yes to all of these.
(However, the term "identical" is not accurate. The classes would be equivalent, not identical.)
RDFS
Wikidata defines its subclass of (P279) property to be equivalent to the rdfs:subClassOf property, so the well-known RDF-Schema semantics apply.
An RDF(S) class has a class extension, which is the set that contains all instances of this class.
If all instances of Class-X are also instances of Class-Y, and all instances of Class-Y are also instances of Class-X, the two classes have the same class extension. In other words: the two classes are equivalent.
RDFS doesn’t define a dedicated property for stating that two classes are equivalent, so this rdfs:subClassOf cycle/loop is the only way to convey it.
OWL
OWL does define a property for that: owl:equivalentClass
Its definition states:

the two class descriptions involved have the same class extension (i.e., both class extensions contain exactly the same set of individuals).

They also add this note, which refers to the cycle/loop:

If we wanted to "upgrade" an axiom of the form "A subClassOf B" to "A equivalentClass B" (meaning that the class extension of A is not just any subset, but in fact the same set as the class extension of B), we could add a second subClassOf axiom of the form (B subClassOf A), which by definition makes the two class extensions equivalent (and thus has the same meaning as "A equivalentClass B"). Such subClassOf "cycles" are explicitly allowed. As OWL is usable in a distributed environment, this can be a useful feature.

